# Ideal op amp equation

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image]

For this question, Vp=Vn
However Im unable to understand how Vo(r1/(r1+r2)) is calculated.

Comment: KCL via SymPy:$$solve([Eq(vn/r1+vn/r2,vin/r1+vo/r2),Eq(vo/r2,io+vn/r2),Eq(vn,vp)],[vo,vn,io])[vo]$$
$$(-r2*vin + vp*(r1 + r2))/r1$$
$$solve([Eq(vn/r1+vn/r2,vin/r1+vo/r2),Eq(vo/r2,io+vn/r2),Eq(vn,vp)],[vo,vn,io])[vo].subs({vin:-3,vp:-5,r1:2e3,r2:10e3})$$
$$-15.0000000000000$$

Comment: It's handy when handling op amps to consider currents. Op amps output whatever they need (can) to make inputs equal voltage. Hence, you have voltage difference - and therefore current - across R1. Follow this logic further and you'll express Vout in terms of Vin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solved for understanding]

Since you already have the solution and simply are not understanding where that is coming from.

\begin{equation*} 
i_1 = -i_2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
i_1= (V_{in} - V_n)/R_1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
i_2=(V_o - V_n) / R_2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{V_{in} - V_n}{R_1} = -\frac{V_o - V_n}{R_2}
\end{equation*}
Solve for Vn:
\begin{equation*}
V_n= V_o \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} + V_{in} \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I was under the assumption that i2 flows in the direction towards Vo and not Vn. Is this because input current has to be 0 therefore i2 cancel outs i1?

Comment: \begin{equation*} i_2=i_{feedback} \end{equation*} 
They are the same current since ideally there is no current entering the op-amp inputs. This is not completely true but pretty close to no current due to extremely high input impedance. The output on the other hand can both source or sink current. In this case it would sink.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure about this although think of it like this. There is not i2 only i1. We say there is i2 to solve it. Or the other way around. The current doesn't just stop at the op amp inverting input. It goes through both resistors. The same current that is.

Comment: You could also say 
\begin{equation*}
i_1=i_2
\end{equation*}
but then:
\begin{equation*}
i_2=\frac{V_n-V_o}{R_2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Alright thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The basic assumption for calculating the gain is the equality Vp=Vn (for any opamp with feedback, operating in its linear range).

The voltage Vp is known (applied) and Vn has to be calculated as a function of Vin and Vo.
Remember that the opamp output for the ideal device is assumed to be zero - and the output does act as a voltage source.

For this reason, the voltage Vn can be found using the superposition theorem because Vn consists of two terms:

1.) Setting Vo=0: Vn1=Vin*R2/(R1+R2)

2.) Setting Vin=0: Vn2=Vo*R1/(R1+R2)

3.) Vn=Vn1+Vn2=Vp=-5V.

4.) From this you can find Vo.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the explanation!